# How can lifetime of reference larger than the lifetime of the type its pointing to?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am playing with this code to to understand lifetimes and elision better. This code compiles.

```
struct Bytes<'a>(&'a [u8]);

impl<'a> Bytes<'a> {
    fn first_two<'b>(self: &'b Bytes<'a>) -> &'b [u8] 
        where 'b: 'a
    {
        &self.0[..2]
    }
}
```

How can the `where` bound `'b: 'a` be acceptable for `self` ? Shouldnt it always be the other way for `self` to be valid?

And the return value points to slice inside `Bytes` whose lifetime is `'a` . So how can the output have lifetime `'b` if `'b` can outlive `'a`?

Comment: Perhaps you are merely reading it backwards? Read `:` as "outlives". So `'a: 'b` means "`'a` outlives `'b`". `'a` must outlive `'b` for `&'b Bytes<'a>` to be well-formed.

Comment: @trentcl You are right . I messed it up while writing the question. I swapped the bounds but it still compiles.

Comment: I’m pretty sure that `&'b Bytes<'a>` implicitly imposes `'a: 'b` which, when taken with your explicit `'b: 'a`, essentially requires that `'a = 'b` (and therefore raises the question of why bother introduce the `'b` lifetime parameter at all, instead of just using `'a` throughout).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's important to notice that the code [compiles](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bfadfd778e7284f84f1abca82982eb90) even when you remove the `where` clause altogether, which should remove any relationship between the two lifetimes. Why is *that* allowed?

I think what happens is that the very existence of a `self: &'b Bytes<'a>` parameter implies the constraint of `'a: 'b`. For any `Bytes<'a>` value to exist in the first place, the caller must ensure that `'a` referenced by `Bytes` lives at least as long as the `Bytes` value itself - hence `'a: 'b`. In other words, returning `&'b [u8]` actually *reduces* the lifetime compared to the original `'a`, which is always allowed.

To return to your code, when you further add `'b: 'a`, you are telling Rust that in addition to the requirement of `'a` living at least as long as `'b`, also `'b` has to live at least as long as `'a`. In other words, `'b` and `'a` must be the same lifetime - which again makes it ok to return `&'b [u8]`, as it's the same as `&'a [u8]`.

> How can the where bound `'b: 'a` be acceptable for `self`? Shouldnt it always be the other way for self to be valid?

Precisely - it should be the other way around for `self` to be valid, and that makes it ok to return `&'b [u8]`. As argued above, adding the seemingly "inverse" constraint doesn't make the first one go away, it just makes the relationship stricter. (It's like knowing that `a >= b` for two numbers, and further stipulating that `b <= a` - the two just boil down to `a == b`.)